# Looping with Application.ontime

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am trying to loop the function below. The goal is to copy and paste from PDF files onto separate worksheets. The basic copy and paste function works, however, when I try to loop it executes each Private Sub 3 times before moving onto the next Private Sub. For example, before Private Sub SecondStep tries to copy and paste from the same PDF three times in a row.

Can anyone help on how to loop this correctly?

```
Sub PDF_Copy_Paste_Loop()

Dim AdobeApp As String
Dim AdobeFile As String
Dim StartAdobe
Dim myfile As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

Do While i < 4


AppActivate "Tests - Excel"

Workbooks("tests").Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

myfile = Cells(i, 1)

AdobeApp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"
AdobeFile = "C:\Users\klanders\Desktop\" & myfile & ".pdf"

StartAdobe = Shell("" & AdobeApp & " " & AdobeFile & "", 1)

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "FirstStep2"
i = i + 1

Loop



End Sub

Private Sub FirstStep()

SendKeys ("^a")
SendKeys ("^c")

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"), "SecondStep2"

End Sub

Private Sub SecondStep()

AppActivate "Book1 - Excel"
Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet" & i).Activate

Range("A1").Select

SendKeys ("^v")

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:06"), "ThirdStep2"


End Sub

Private Sub ThirdStep()

Sheets.Add

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help (not tested)

```
Option Explicit

Sub PDF_Copy_Paste_Loop()
    Dim AdobeApp As String, AdobeFile As String
    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

    'out of the loop (static value)
    AdobeApp = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 10.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"

    Set wb = Workbooks("Book1")
    Set ws = Workbooks("tests").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    i = 1
    Do While i < 4
        AdobeFile = "C:\Users\klanders\Desktop\" & ws.Cells(i, 1).Value2 & ".pdf"
        Shell AdobeApp & " " & AdobeFile, 1
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02") 'pause 2 seconds
            SendKeys "^a"
            SendKeys "^c"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
            AppActivate "Book1 - Excel"
            wb.Worksheets(i).Range("A1").Select
            SendKeys "^v"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:02")
        wb.Worksheets.Add
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```